# Automatically authenticate a user who logged in using Facebook (ZF2)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm using ZfcUser in a ZF2 application. What I'm trying to do is to allow a person to authenticate using Facebook. The Facebook authentication part works fine: I request a login URL from the Graph API, redirect the user to login and request permissions, Facebook redirects back to my redirect URL and then I can fetch a Facebook session object and retrieve the user's info.

I would like it to work like this:
- If e-mail address doesn't exist as a user in my database I will create the user and I want to automatically login with that local user profile.
- If there's already a user in the database with that e-mail address I want to login as that user without having to authenticate.

\Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService (which is used by ZfcUser) has a getIdentity() method to retrieve the current identity. It also has an authenticate method with an adapter parameter to perform authentication. There is no setIdentity() method, so I'm guessing I will have to create a custom authentication adapter and use that to login a user who logged in using Facebook. Is that true or is there an easier or better way?

**Edit:**
This does work:

```
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('zfcuser_auth_service');
$user = ...
$authService->getStorage()->write($user);
```

It seems a bit dirty though, but I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel ;)

https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth

Before doing something, it's always a good idea to check http://modules.zendframework.com/

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I saw this module too. I will have a closer look at it when I want to add different types of social logins. For instance, I'm not sure if that module is capable of cooperating with local user profiles. For now I'll just work with my solution as it does exactly what I want it to do.